# Nuclide Automatic fix all eslint errors

Tags: atom-editor, eslint, nuclide-editor

In Atom-Nuclide for simple errors (indentation, semicolons, const etc) it appears a tooltip with a button to fix it automatically.

[image]

This is very useful but still a bit time consuming.

Is there a way to automate it with a command or a macro that simulates clicking on all the fix buttons?

Comment: Update: found useful to autocorrect many eslint errors (mostly punctuations) when adding esformatter and a series of plugins (  "esformatter-quotes", "esformatter-add-trailing-commas","esformatter-braces","esformatter-ignore")

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the eslint fix tooltip without installing the nuclide package? I'm currently using linter and linter-eslint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Alt+Shift+A` does what you want (default on Linux). 
The command is called "Nuclide Diagnostics: Fix all errors in current file", I found it using the [command-palette](https://github.com/atom/command-palette).